# Retrieving a Set in Hibernate mapping in many-to-many

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping

I want to get the outcomes set from the Complaint class which is a hibernate entity from the Complaints Table. This table has a many-to-many relationship with a Table named Complaint_Outcome_Type and a join table named Complaint_Outcome.

Here is the Complaint and ComplaintOutcomeType classes

```
public class Complaint extends ComplaintBase{

    private set<ComplaintOutcomeType> outcomes;

}

public class ComplaintOutcomeType {
    private String code;
}
```

In ComplaintBase.hbm.xml I have

```
<class name="registrationdb.domain.ComplaintBase" table="COMPLAINT_BASE">
...
<joined-subclass name="registrationdb.domain.Complaint" table="COMPLAINT">
        <key> 
            <column name="COMPLAINT_ID"/>
        </key>
...
<set name="outcomes" table="COMPLAINT_OUTCOME" >
    <key column="COMPLAINT_ID" not-null="true"/>
    <many-to-many column="CODE" class="registrationdb.domain.reference.ComplaintOutcomeType" />
</set>
...
</class>
```

In ComplaintOutcomeType.hbm.xml I have

```
<class     name="registrationdb.domain.reference.ComplaintOutcomeType"     table="COMPLAINT_OUTCOME_TYPE">
    <id name="code" type="string" column="CODE" />
    <property name="description" type="string" column="DESCRIPTION" />
    <property name="displaySequence" type="integer" column="DISPLAY_SEQUENCE" />
</class>
```

Here is my query string

```
    String queryString = "select complaint.id, complaint.subject, complaint.complainant, complaint.openedDate, complaint.closedDate ";
    queryString = queryString + "from registrationdb.domain.Complaint as complaint ";
    queryString = queryString + "where complaint.subject.id = :complaintSubjectId and complaint.outcomes";
```

What I want to do is get the set of complaint outcomes for each complaint, so I can check if there is a complaint outcome of a particular type.

eg complaint.getOutcomes().contains(ComplaintType ...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use? If you use JPA, you can just get the list of complaint first like this:

```
String queryString = "select complaint from Complaint where complaint.subject.id = :complaintSubjectId";
```

it will return you a list of complaint. For each complaint, you can get the outcome set in the code:

```
complaint.getOutcomes()
```